# how to get google cloud storage real time file upload feedback?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to display a progress bar on my app with the help of 'state_changed' event listener. But I only got "0" and "100". there would be a way to get the whole process? I am following the code described in the [cloud storage docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask).
the image specific code:

[image]

could anyone help me?

I would like to have like 0...1...2..3..4..5...100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Google File Upload with Progress Bar WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472013/asynchronous-google-file-upload-with-progress-bar-wpf)

Comment: Also, take a look at this. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20803

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage can't be configured for the behavior you want.  It uses an internal buffer to manage reading and writing, and it only measures write progress when that internal buffer has been fully written.  You are probably just uploading a relatively small file (smaller than that buffer), which means your progress goes immediately to 100% after that buffer is written.

If you want different behavior, you can always modify the source code to make it do what you want.  But merely decreasing the size of the buffer will likely slow your uploads.